# Reverse the [google-closure-compiler] tag synonym which points to [google-closure]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

On Oct 5, the [google-closure-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-compiler) tag was made a synonym of [google-closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure). That's extremely confusing and I'd like to just burninate the [google-closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure) tag entirely. As an active member of the compiler - we use and link to the [google-closure-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-compiler) tag.

"Closure" was a suite of tools released by Google in 2009 - however only Closure-Library and Closure-Compiler are well known at all and questions between those two rarely are answered by the same people.

Once in a while there is a specific question about using Closure Library with Closure Compiler - in that case only are both tags applicable. For instance, while I'm the top answerer on [google-closure-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-compiler), I have almost no answers on [google-closure-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-library).

For further evidence, the npm package names are also google-closure-library and google-closure-compiler.

Once the [google-closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure) tag synonym has been reversed, I will go through and appropriately retag all questions with it and ask for it to be burninated.

Can we please reverse the tag synonym?

Comment: It looks like the synonym request started in 2010, so that took the full 6 to 8 years to complete ... Let's hope it doesn't take that long to reverse ...

Comment: Yeah - it's bad. Hopefully since I'm willing to do all the work to retag the questions (and have the necessary privileges), this won't take as long.

Comment: Agree this should be reversed.

Comment: Related [Give the power to the community to revert back a tag synonymization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230967/213575)

Comment: I've removed the syn... it might take the system a little bit for it to take effect...